# AS 3.0 addChild functionality in JSFL?

Tags: flash, actionscript, jsfl

Is there a way besides pasting frames inside a layer to add an element into a timeline? I'd like to replicate the addChild functionality from actionScript into JSFL. So basically, I'd like to add a bunch of movieClips instances into another movie clip, does anyone know how to do this in JSFL? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can provide more details ? Would addChild work a bit like this? addChild('libraryName') - fetches a symbol from the library by it's name and places it on the stage in the current layer/frame ? or addChild('libraryName',parentSymbol) ? or something else ?

Comment: This is not action script, it's JSFL, the extended script functionality / language for flash to do custom things inside an .FLA, like converting all the graphic items in your library to movie clips.

Comment: addChild('libraryName') is not an actionscript function and is does not fetch a symbol from library ;) Assume that was a JSFL function. I thought the arguments would give that away. Back to your question: what would the funtion do ? (provide a use case)

Answer (score 2):

It can be done like this:

```
var itemIndex = fl.getDocumentDOM().library.findItemIndex("childMovieClipName");
var theItem = fl.getDocumentDOM().library.items[itemIndex];
fl.getDocumentDOM().addItem({x:0,y:0}, theItem);
```

If you want to adjust something of the new child, use doc.setElementProperty , like this:

```
fl.getDocumentDOM().setElementProperty("x", 0);
fl.getDocumentDOM().setElementProperty("y", 0);
```

Comment: Thanks! I already figured it out using the addItemToDocument function from the library (I didn't wanted to add the clip to the stage)

Comment: How does it know which element instance to target?